# How to deploy java application with external jars using java web start

Tags: java, java-web-start

I am new to java web start. I try to use it to deploy my java application. When I launch the app using JNLP. The app was broken because it could not find the external jars. Can anyone help?

This app is a swing application to upload files to server through sftp, and it uses some external jars. I created an app.jar to include all class I have written, and put all external jars in a folder called lib. All jars are signed. It works fine when I run it from my local computer by java -jar app.jar. After I uploaded all jar files into a folder (APP) in ROOT Tomacat7. The java web start can launch the app, but it got stuck in the middle because of Exception of java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError caused by missing external jars.

app.jar is in APP, and all external jars are in APP/lib. The jnlp file is also in APP, and as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://serverIP:8080/APP/" href="test.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>test</title>
    <vendor>test</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://serverIP:8080/APP/" /> 
    <description>test</description> 
  </information>
 <security>
   <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <update check="always" policy="always"/>
  <resources>
    <!-- Application Resources -->
    <property name="jnlp.packEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <j2se version="1.6+" />  
    <jar href="app.jar" main="true" />
    <jar href="lib/externalA.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/externalB.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/externalC.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/externalD.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/externalE.jar" />
    <jar href="lib/externalF.jar" />
  </resources>
  <application-desc
    name="Test"
    main-class="guiClient.GUIClient"
    width="300"
    height="300">
  </application-desc>

</jnlp>
```

Comment: The jnlp looks fine to me. What's the exception? copy and paste the full trace.

Comment: When you paste `http://serverIP:8080/APP/lib/externalA.jar` in your browser address bar and hit enter, what do you get?  I.E. 1) the Jar 2) An error page. 3) Something else?

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your suggestion. When I past http://serverIP:8080/APP/lib/externalA.jar in the browser address bar, I got the jar file.